# Create iOS App using Apple iOS Provisioning Portal

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, pushsharp

I'm trying to create iOS App using Apple iOS Provisioning Portal to make Push Notifications in iOS.

Do I need to make join to apple developer program to be able to create new iOS App?

How can I open Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles window to be able to create new iOS App?

any ideas to help me please.

Comment: did you make some research on web? I don't think so :(

Comment: yes, you will need apple developer account for that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013839-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Please do not post answers that are just a link, the link can move to another location or the site could go down, leaving the answer useless. Post the relevant information from the site here as your answer and provide the link incase further research is needed